# Apache getting 403 for new files

Tags: apache, centos, centos7, httpd.conf

I have a web app in which users can see image and videos.
But I'm always getting 403 Permission denied when I tried to see any image or video.

I checked the permission of the file and it's

```
drwxrwxrwx.   2 apache apache  4096 Jul 12 09:57 ads
drwxrwxrwx.   5 apache apache  4096 Jul 12 09:58 img
drwxrwxrwx.   3 apache apache  4096 Jul 12 09:58 programs
drwxrwxrwx.   2 apache apache  4096 Jul 12 09:58 seassons
drwxrwxrwx.   2 apache apache  4096 Jul 18 08:34 temp
drwxrwxrwx. 374 apache apache 24576 Jul 18 08:34 videos
```

I'm trying to open the image in those folders in a web browser when the server is httpd.

If I run the following commands everything start working but for EXISTING files... If a user upload a new file, that will get 403 again until I run again the commands.

```
sudo chmod -R g+r /videos
sudo chown -R apache /videos
```

And my httpd.config is

```
<Directory "/var/www">
AllowOverride All
# Allow open access:
Require all granted
```

## Further relax access to the default document root:

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

My OS is Centos7

The new files are created with the following permissions:

```
-rw-r-----. 1 tomcat tomcat 386688 Jul 18 09:14 mynewfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Your apache process can't access the files because of the permissions set when it's created, so you need to change this. I don't know why your new files' owner/group is set to Tomcat - that's got to be the user that some process is running as (not Apache?). To set permissions on newly created filesna directory look at the`umask` command - this sets permissions on newly created files in the current directory. Try `umask 022` in each directory to set default permissions to user writeable, world readable.